# Having trouble getting latitude and longitude on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-gps

I'm working on an Android Studio App and want to retrieve the latitude and longitude of the device so I can send it to a Web Service and do some logic using it. The problem is I can't seem to get around getting the latitude and longitude. Here's my code:

All of this is inside my onCreate() method on my launcher activity, so it's running when the app starts:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            TextView coords = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coords);
            coords.setText("Suas coordenadas: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
        }
    };
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if ((checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET
            }, 10);
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET
            }, 10);
        }
    } else {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);
```

When i Debug the application, this happens:

It creates the two locationmanager and listeners, 
checks the build.versions as true (SDK_INT is 23 and M is 23 aswell)
when it checks for the permissions, it crashers and goes into the else statement where it requests the permissions

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);
            }
            return;
    }
}
```

Here the code gets the requestCode as 10, and runs the requestLocationUpdates.

No error up until there, but i debugged the "OnLocationChanged" inside the LocationListener, but the app never gets there and doesn't update the coords TextView.

What am I doing wrong?

Info:
build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "vehicleassistant.com.br.vehicleassistant"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 14
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I'm running the minSDK version on a lower version because this is a production app not a learning/tutorial app and I want to get to the most number of devices possible. 
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

As requested the manifest permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

and the entire OnCreate() method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Salvando contexto da aplicação no singleton para ser visto e usado por toda a aplicação
        Singleton.ContextMainActivity = getApplicationContext();
        //Inicializando banco local com dados de cidade baixadas
        try {
            Singleton.bancoCidadesBaixadas = new BancoCidadesBaixadas(Singleton.ContextMainActivity);
            Singleton.bancoCidadesBaixadas.onCreate(Singleton.bancoCidadesBaixadas.getWritableDatabase());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Banco criado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Banco não criado: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //Inicializando e pedindo permissão do usuario para utilizar serviços de GPS para pegar localização.
        // Caso o GPS esteja desligado, o usuario é redirecionado para a tela de configurações para habilitá-lo.
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                TextView coords = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coords);
                coords.setText("Suas coordenadas: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            }
        };
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if ((checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                }, 10);
            } else {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.INTERNET
                }, 10);
            }
        } else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);
        }

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        loadingBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingBar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        itemGroup = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).getSubMenu();
        itemSubmenu0 = itemGroup.getItem(0);
        itemSubmenu1 = itemGroup.getItem(1);
//        itemSubmenu2 = itemGroup.getItem(2);
        itemMenu1 = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1);
        itemMenu2 = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(2);
        itemSubmenu0.setChecked(true);
        //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new MapsFragment()).commit();

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        /*Inicia uma transação para conseguir adicionar um fragment na activity
        * Coment. Alex Sousa*/
        showFragment(new MainFragment(), "Inicio");
    }
```

Comment: Do you also set the permissions in the Android Manifest?

Comment: yes I did, sorry I didn't mention that. Here is the snippet:

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

Comment: post your complete code.

Comment: @ChristianW.A.Hess Place the code in your question. It looks better :)

Comment: @deejay those are the only things I added to the code to try and get the location status. There rest of the code is mainly setOnClickListeners and DrawerMenu and Toolbar configurations. But i'll edit and add the entire OnCreate() method

Comment: are you testing on a emulator? because you can't get onLocationChanged method in Emulator. unless you use some fake gps location tools.

Comment: @deejay I'm running both on emulator and on my Device. Neither work. It's an Asus Zenfone 2 running Android 6.0 - API 23